# Why does css transition on an icon/link cause it to redraw in the wrong place after transition has been applied?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am having an issue identifying why after a CSS transition is applied on an icon/link it redraws in the wrong place.

Here is demo of it happening: https://jsfiddle.net/9n4edjzc/

```css
div.rotate > a {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.rotate > a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Why do the icons/links redraw in the wrong place after hover?</p>
<div class="rotate"> <a href="http://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a>  <a href="http://linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="http://rssfeed.com/rss"><i class="fa fa-rss-square fa-2x"></i></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, your code doesn't work at all in firefox, or IE, and acts funny in chrome.  You can fix Chrome and firefox by adding `display:inline-block` to `div.rotate > a` and you can fix IE by placing `transform: rotate(360deg);` inside `div.rotate > a:hover`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your links need to be block elements to begin with if they have images.

then you need containers so set them out properly.

the main requirement though is having your links as block elements.

**Fixed**

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.rotate a {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  display:block;
  
}
ul.rotate a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Why do the icons/links redraw in the wrong place after hover?</p>

<ul class="rotate">
  <li>
    <a href="http://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://rssfeed.com/rss"><i class="fa fa-rss-square fa-2x"></i></a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still need to fix IE by placing `transform: rotate(360deg);` inside `ul.rotate a:hover`

Comment: His query wasn't about cross browser support we don't know that he needs to have IE do anything..

Comment: The query also didn't end with "... in chome" either.  Including `transform: rotate(360deg);` is the standard way of doing what he wants and not doing it is just bad coding -- Assuming that the other browsers will continue to support their vendor prefixed versions forever.

Comment: Yes.  Your proposed answer only works in some browsers, and I would hate to see others use it as a basis for learning.

Comment: My answer is built from his code alone. I do not make assumptions if it makes you feel better I will add it in.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I wasn't thinking about IE support yet, but its good to be mindful. Both of your inputs lead me to a better solution than that with which I started. Kudos and Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `display: inline-block;` to `div.rotate > a`

**SNIPPET**

```css
div.rotate > a {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.rotate > a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Why do the icons/links redraw in the wrong place after hover?</p>
<div class="rotate"> <a href="http://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a>  <a href="http://linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="http://rssfeed.com/rss"><i class="fa fa-rss-square fa-2x"></i></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yup that did it. It would be great if you could briefly explain why that works. Cheers.

Comment: @DCdaz answer is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the anchor inline-block like this:

```css
div.rotate > a {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.rotate > a:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Why do the icons/links redraw in the wrong place after hover?</p>
<div class="rotate">
  <a href="http://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a> 
  <a href="http://linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="http://rssfeed.com/rss"><i class="fa fa-rss-square fa-2x"></i></a> 
</div>
```

This works in all current browsers and is standard compliant, unlike the other answers that only work in some of them.  It is also a lot cleaner as well.

This is probably a better way, if you don't mind changing the HTML:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
a.rotate {
    display: block;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a.rotate:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Why do the icons/links redraw in the wrong place after hover?</p>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://github.com/" class="rotate"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://linkedin.com/" class="rotate"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://rssfeed.com/rss" class="rotate"><i class="fa fa-rss-square fa-2x"></i></a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```